# Generic tablets and single board computers

Tags: pcb-design, design, android, motherboard

I've been pondering the idea for a while now in regards to a project I've had in mind. Essentially, I was wondering how I would go about obtaining generic tablet/phone motherboard designs? Would I be able to license them from anywhere in order to have them manufactured someplace else if need be?

The same goes for single board computers like the Raspberry pi zero W; My brother has a project he has in mind and was wondering the same question. Would we be able to buy generic ones in mass from a vendor, buy the schematic or would we have to design our own?

Obviously, I expect this to not be easy what so ever, but It's a long term project and I would like to have all my options to consider now rather than later.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_ZeroW_1p1_reduced.pdf

Comment: @JSLavertu Thank you, that's a great lead! I presume I'll have to design my own at some point which is a bit unfortunate, but I expected that.

Comment: If you are actually contemplating production you can get a small factory to white label an existing or customized design of theirs.  But this is only one of the many challenges you will face.  If you read the site guidance you'll see the question doesn't really fit here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks! I'll scout some out. I wasn't too sure where to go with this question in regards to stack overflow, but I figured electrical engineering was a solid place.

Comment: There probably isn't a good place for this in the SE system, as whole idea of SE is for highly specific questions.  Part of your challenge will be how fast the offerings in this field change.  But if you look on an e-commerce aggregator you'll see lots of places that would love to sell you a container full of semi-custom tablets.  Much of the related hassle of having a _product_ will however fall to you, in ways such a vendor may not be eager to emphasize.

Comment: From a software perspective you are all over the place and need to narrow the scope of your project.  A tablet (assuming it is designed to run Android) is related to Unix but each application is treated like a user.  A Raspberry Pi runs something more like Unix called Linux.  Running applications on these two operating systems is very different.  And depending on what the application is expected to do, usually not trivial in the making.